# How would Google react to a page ordered differently to how it is presented?

Tags: jquery, seo, search-engine

I have reordered the index page of my site to put the banner and the menu to the bottom of the page and used jQuery to display them at the top on the front end.
I've done this so that the content is closer to the top to allow Google to index it easier without having to find its way through the banner and menu first.

Would Google penalise me for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Google do not penalize for putting menu bar at the bottom. Use webpage mark up properly by using HTML5 Tags like `<nav>` for menu items. I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: So I'm okay for putting the menu bar at the bottom on the page in the source but displaying it at the top of the page on the front end? Is the correct?

Comment: I reason I ask is that Google penalise you for having things in the source that don't dipslay the same on the front end, like text that is the same colour as the background.

Comment: I can not really say if google penalizes for color and for the rest of the reasons. First of all, are you having any trouble in indexing and ranking factor? If so, how can you be so sure?  It all depends on what you want. I suggest you to experiment once at top and once at bottom like that. Stick to whatever that performing better in indexing your navigation.